# Read .obj file in LWJGL not loaded correctly

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a problem with my .obj-file reader. The .obj-File looks like the following:

```
# Blender3D v249 OBJ File: untitled.blend
# www.blender3d.org
mtllib cube.mtl
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.748573 0.750412
vt 0.749279 0.501284
vt 0.999110 0.501077
vt 0.999455 0.750380
vt 0.250471 0.500702
vt 0.249682 0.749677
vt 0.001085 0.750380
vt 0.001517 0.499994
vt 0.499422 0.500239
vt 0.500149 0.750166
vt 0.748355 0.998230
vt 0.500193 0.998728
vt 0.498993 0.250415
vt 0.748953 0.250920
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn -1.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000
vn -0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
vn -0.000001 0.000000 1.000000
vn 1.000000 -0.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000001
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
vn -0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
usemtl Material_ray.png
s off
f 5/1/1 1/2/1 4/3/1
f 5/1/1 4/3/1 8/4/1
f 3/5/2 7/6/2 8/7/2
f 3/5/2 8/7/2 4/8/2
f 2/9/3 6/10/3 3/5/3
f 6/10/4 7/6/4 3/5/4
f 1/2/5 5/1/5 2/9/5
f 5/1/6 6/10/6 2/9/6
f 5/1/7 8/11/7 6/10/7
f 8/11/7 7/12/7 6/10/7
f 1/2/8 2/9/8 3/13/8
f 1/2/8 3/13/8 4/14/8
```

Model-Loader-Class:

```
package com.crystalcode.lwjgl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Model
{
    private ArrayList <Vector3f> vertexList;
    private ArrayList <Vector3f> textureList;
    private ArrayList <Vector3f> normalList;

    public Model(String obj)
    {
        vertexList = new ArrayList<>();
        textureList = new ArrayList<>();
        normalList = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {           
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(obj));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.startsWith("f "))
                {
                    // Split the line
                        String[] values = line.split(" ");

                    // Parse the vertex indices
                        float v1 = Float.parseFloat(values[1].split("/")[0]);
                        float v2 = Float.parseFloat(values[2].split("/")[0]);
                        float v3 = Float.parseFloat(values[3].split("/")[0]);

                        Vector3f vertex = new Vector3f(v1, v2, v3);
                        vertexList.add(vertex);

                    // Parse the texture indices
                        float vt1 = Float.parseFloat(values[1].split("/")[1]);
                        float vt2 = Float.parseFloat(values[2].split("/")[1]);
                        float vt3 = Float.parseFloat(values[3].split("/")[1]);

                        Vector3f texture = new Vector3f(vt1, vt2, vt3);
                        textureList.add(texture);

                    // Parse the normal indices
                        float vn1 = Float.parseFloat(values[1].split("/")[2]);
                        float vn2 = Float.parseFloat(values[2].split("/")[2]);
                        float vn3 = Float.parseFloat(values[3].split("/")[2]);

                        Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(vn1, vn2, vn3);
                        normalList.add(normal);

                    // Debug
                        System.out.println ("Vertex: " + vertex.toString() + "\t\tTexture: " + texture.toString() + "\tNormal: " + normal.toString());

                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public float[] getVertex()
    {       
        int counter = 0;

        float[] vertexArray;
        vertexArray = new float[vertexList.size() * 3];

        for (Vector3f vertex : vertexList)
        {
            vertexArray[counter + 0] = vertex.x;
            vertexArray[counter + 1] = vertex.y;
            vertexArray[counter + 2] = vertex.z;

            counter += 3;
        }

        return vertexArray;
    }

    public float[] getColor()
    {       
        int counter = 0;

        float[] colorArray;
        colorArray = new float[vertexList.size() * 3];

        for (Vector3f vertex : vertexList)
        {
            colorArray[counter + 0] = (float) Math.random();
            colorArray[counter + 1] = (float) Math.random();
            colorArray[counter + 2] = (float) Math.random();

            counter += 3;
        }

        return colorArray;
    }
}
```

The faces will be read out like the following:

```
Vertex: Vector3f[5.0, 1.0, 4.0]     Texture: Vector3f[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]    Normal: Vector3f[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[5.0, 4.0, 8.0]     Texture: Vector3f[1.0, 3.0, 4.0]    Normal: Vector3f[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[3.0, 7.0, 8.0]     Texture: Vector3f[5.0, 6.0, 7.0]    Normal: Vector3f[2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[3.0, 8.0, 4.0]     Texture: Vector3f[5.0, 7.0, 8.0]    Normal: Vector3f[2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[2.0, 6.0, 3.0]     Texture: Vector3f[9.0, 10.0, 5.0]   Normal: Vector3f[3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[6.0, 7.0, 3.0]     Texture: Vector3f[10.0, 6.0, 5.0]   Normal: Vector3f[4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[1.0, 5.0, 2.0]     Texture: Vector3f[2.0, 1.0, 9.0]    Normal: Vector3f[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[5.0, 6.0, 2.0]     Texture: Vector3f[1.0, 10.0, 9.0]   Normal: Vector3f[6.0, 6.0, 6.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[5.0, 8.0, 6.0]     Texture: Vector3f[1.0, 11.0, 10.0]  Normal: Vector3f[7.0, 7.0, 7.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[8.0, 7.0, 6.0]     Texture: Vector3f[11.0, 12.0, 10.0] Normal: Vector3f[7.0, 7.0, 7.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]     Texture: Vector3f[2.0, 9.0, 13.0]   Normal: Vector3f[8.0, 8.0, 8.0]
Vertex: Vector3f[1.0, 3.0, 4.0]     Texture: Vector3f[2.0, 13.0, 14.0]  Normal: Vector3f[8.0, 8.0, 8.0]
```

But if I render the VBO it looks like the following:

[image]

The texture is ignored and the quads are filled with random colors.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Without code it is kinda hard to tell, but your texture coordinates look wrong. They should be in the [0 - 1] range.

Answer (score 0):

Per your code, the vertex colors seem to be generated in `getColor()` using Math.random(). Are you uploading the image texture in some other code as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, now I see. You are using the indices of the texture coordinates **as** the coordinates itself. You should take a look at the [specs of the OBJ file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Face_definitions). Faces are made by linking vertices, normals and texture coordinates together.